# NGINX Amazon EC2 keeps loading through 80 port is allowed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, security-groups

I'm trying to host ubuntu 18.4 server on aws ec2 instance.
[Here is my security group allowed port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Vlx.png) 
Though I've allowed 80 port but when i try to see on browser using my public ip it wont loading but it suppose to show nginx welcome screen.

`netstat -tuanp | grep 80`

output

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16912/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16912/nginx: master
```

My nginx is running perfectly . Here is the status
[nginx status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsSLp.png)

My browser showing:

> This site can’t be reached `my_public_ip` took too long to respond.

Please Help!

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the ports to the correct addresses?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the I opened the port of the correct addresses